# Загрузка данных таблицы Excel как объекты класса БД

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

Предусмотрен функционал загрузки таблицы Excel в программу и отображение ее в DataGrid[image: так программа выгружает данные из таблицы]

Но мне необходимо взаимодействовать с самими значениями. Нужно хотя бы выгрузить строчки как объекты класса.

Comment: Не совсем понятно (мне). Нужно что? Добраться до значений? Если Файл загружается - то все значения в программе - обращайтесь к источнику в который она загружается. Или она еще НЕ загружена и вы пытаетесь это сделать? Уточните пожалуйста.